# How to merge array of keys and arrays of values into an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have the following arrays:

```
var a = ["F", "M"];
var b = ["female", "male"];
var c = ["fa-female", "fa-male"];
```

and I am able to assign `b` to `a` using for loop with:

```
ans[a[i]] = values[i]; // { M: "male", F: "female" }
```

how would I go about adding the third array and assign it to `a` as well?

```
{ M: {"male", "fa-male"}, F: {"female", "fa-female"} }
```

or something similar?

**EDIT:** Result could either be an array or an object.

Comment: you want to create a object or a array

Comment: what your desire output from these 3 arrays?

Comment: object or array is fine. it's a bit confusing since the variables are array but console.log 
displays it as an object.

Comment: hmm.. you have no predicate or conditional statements here.  Are we assuming three arrays, where first array is a key index and we are correlating by position?

Comment: @BrettCaswell yes that's it, the first array would act as the key index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this one.

```
var a = ["F", "M"];
var b = ["female", "male"];
var c = ["fa-female", "fa-male"];

var resultArray = [];
for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    resultArray [a[i]] = [b[i], c[i]];
}
```

Comment: @budji I have rolled back your edit. This isn't what the author of this answer intended. If you think it should be changed, leave a reply here or find a better answer ;)

Comment: as an alternative to an array here, you could do an object, `var resultObject = Object.assign({});`.. same loop for assignment.  difference would be type handling on `resultObject` with enumeration and property accessor support.  i.e. `resultObject.m` or `resultObject["m"]`, and the enumeration `for(key in resultObject) resultObject[key]`

Answer (score 4):

Using [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries), you can build an array of `[key, value]` pairs by mapping ([`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)) each `key` (ie: value) from `a` to an array of values from the same index from all the other arrays:

```js
const a = ["F", "M"];
const b = ["female", "male"];
const c = ["fa-female", "fa-male"];

const buildObj = (keys, ...values) => Object.fromEntries(keys.map(
  (key, i) => [key, values.map(arr => arr[i])]
));
  
const res = buildObj(a, b, c);
console.log(res);
```

`Object.fromEntries()` has [limited browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries#Browser_compatibility), however, it can easily be polyfilled. Alternatively, instead of using an object, you could use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), which would remove the need of `.fromEntries()`:

```js
const a = ["F", "M"];
const b = ["female", "male"];
const c = ["fa-female", "fa-male"];

const buildMap = (keys, ...values) => new Map(keys.map(
  (key, i) => [key, values.map(arr => arr[i])]
));
  
const res = buildMap(a, b, c);
console.log("See browser console:", res); // see browser console for output
```

Comment: Thanks @NickParsons, I tried your solution as well, and it gave me the same result as the selected answer which is simpler for my purpose.

Comment: @budji ok, no worries. But I suggest that you change `var resultArray = [];` to `var resultArray = {};` if you're going to use the accepted answer as you really want an object as your output ;)

Comment: Using `Object.fromEntries` is definitely the way to go IMHO, so +1. It's a shame it doesn't provide a function for handling collision.

Comment: @customcommander thanks :). I agree, it is a shame it doesn't provide some way to handle collisions, would be a useful feature.

Comment: both this answer and @customcommander's answer are intriguing - as I was not familiar with `fromEntries` method.  It's important to note the enumerable nature to using object `{}` budji. `object.key` or `object[key]`.

Answer (score 2):

You could combine your arrays to form key/value pairs for `Object.fromEntries`:

```js
Object.fromEntries([['M', 'male'], ['F', 'female']]);
//=> {M: 'male', F: 'female'}
```

However `Object.fromEntries` does not handle collisions:

```js
Object.fromEntries([['M', 'male'], ['F', 'female'], ['F', 'fa-female']]);
//=> {M: 'male', F: 'fa-female'}
```

As you can see, the previous value for `F` just got overridden :/

We can build a custom `fromEntries` function that puts values into arrays:

```js
const fromEntries =
    pairs =>
      pairs.reduce((obj, [k, v]) => ({
        ...obj,
        [k]: k in obj
          ? [].concat(obj[k], v)
          : [v]
      }), {});

fromEntries([['M', 'male'], ['M', 'fa-male'], ['F', 'female'], ['F', 'fa-female']]);
//=> {M: ["male", "fa-male"], F: ["female", "fa-female"]}
```

---

**How do you create key/value pairs then?**

One possible solution: `zip`

```js
const zip = (x, y) => x.map((v, i) => [v, y[i]]);

zip(['F', 'M'], ['female', 'male']);
//=> [["F", "female"], ["M", "male"]]
```

So to produce all pairs (and your final object)

```js
fromEntries([
  ...zip(['F', 'M'], ['female', 'male']),
  ...zip(['F', 'M'], ['fa-female', 'fa-male'])
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   var a = ["male","female"];
   var b = ["m","f"];
   var c = ["fa male","fa female"];

   var result = a.reduce((res,val,key) => {
     var temp = [b,c];
     res[val] = temp.map((v) => v[key]);
     return res;
   },{});
```

This is bit expensive. It is a nested loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one line with `forEach`. Another way using reduce and Map.

```js
var a = ["F", "M"];
var b = ["female", "male"];
var c = ["fa-female", "fa-male"];

const ans = {};
a.forEach((key, i) => (ans[key] = [b[i], c[i]]));

console.log(ans)

// Alternate way
var ans2 = Object.fromEntries(
  a.reduce((acc, curr, i) => acc.set(curr, [b[i], c[i]]), new Map())
);

console.log(ans2);
```

Answer (score -1):

A solution using map and filter

```
var a = ["M", "F"];
var b = ["female", "male"];
var c = ["fa-female", "fa-male"];

const bAndC = b.concat(c);
let returnObj = {};
a.map(category => {
let catArray = []

if(category === 'F') {
    catArray = bAndC.filter(item => item.includes('female'));
} else {
    catArray = bAndC.filter(item => item.includes('male') && !item.includes('female'));
}
    return returnObj[category] = catArray;
});
```